# jstree drag drop within a tree

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jstree

I have a jstree. I am facing a problem while dragging and dropping a node. It is described as below -

```
t1
t2
t3
t4
```

Lets say I want to move t4 between t2 and t3. When I drag t4, there is a marker-helper-line shown where I am putting the node. If I release my mouse when the marker line is exactly between t2 and t3 then dragging does not work, whereas if I drag t4 between t2 and t3 such that either t2 or t3 are highlighted then dragging works.

This happens when I am using jquery version 1.7.0 or higher.
http://jsfiddle.net/LLzC3/

If I use jquery 1.6.4 or lower this issue is not observed and it works perfectly.
http://jsfiddle.net/Jx9Xw/

Please let me know if any more information is needed. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which browser are you using for testing, both of demo fiddle works for me on chrome(29.0.1547.66 m) and firefox(23.0.1).

Comment: I am using Firefox 23 and chrome 29.0.1547.65. Did you all tried to keep the marker-line exactly in between the 2 nodes. Try zooming the browser screen to 200% and then check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fix adding this :

```
#jstree-marker-line 
 {
 z-index: -1000 !important;
 }
 .jstree-focused.jstree-default
 {
 background-color:transparent !important;
 }
```

Let's see :http://jsfiddle.net/CqDNT/

Comment: your fiddle works good +1. But when I implement in my project that marker line is not displayed at all.

Comment: I have reproduced issue what I am facing using your solution. See here - http://jsfiddle.net/LLzC3/1/

Comment: after lots of tries, i don't find any solution. For me, the 1px height is faulty, when we release over the marker (border and shadow included), the folder goes back. Sorry. It's all i can do.

Comment: ok. BTW I implemented above solution. It hides the marker line but just the arrow to left of the node looks good. So it is accepted for me.